# Replacement part for 2010 Specialized Tricross BB shift cable guide

Tags: cable-routing

My 2010 Specialized Tricross has a plastic cable guide under the bottom bracket:
[image]

Mine is worn and one cable is starting to rub the frame metal as detailed in my recent answer [here](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/88247/11416).

What's the correct replacement part? Is it a model-specific part or a generic part? I found [this question](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/30602/shifter-cable-running-beneath-the-bottom-bracket-without-a-sheath) about the same part, and there's a link to a generic part on amazon there, where I found several other generic offerings. Can I buy pretty much any "MTB Bottom Bracket Shifter Cable Guide" and assume it will do the job?

Thanks.

Comment: It really depends on the details of how it is attached to the frame. Some have a plastic molded finger sticking out to fit into a hole in the frame. Once you remove yours, you can see exactly what you need. Name brand like Shimano will likely be better quality; just be sure to save your screw!

Answer (score 2):

One version of the 2010 Tricross was specc'd with Shimano's Claris groupset. The Shimano part number for a "bottom bracket cable guide" is SM-SP17.

One can also use a couple of short sections of shift housing in place of the cable guide. Two, 2-3 inch pieces of shift cable can be slipped on over each of the inner cables to the point under the bottom bracket.  Inner cable tension holds them fast in position under the BB shell. The inner cables slides just as freely thru the housing sections as it would on a cable guide. The bike's paint and metal are also protected by the housing segments.  I cannot quickly find the article  that this tip comes from, but it is an idea from the mind of Sheldon Brown, an east coast bike mechanic and pioneer of web-based bicycle reference. See sheldonbrown.com.